# How to undo a commit in SVN?

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subversion: Retract Accidental Checkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747713/subversion-retract-accidental-checkin)

How do you undo a commit of a file in SVN?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330011/how-do-i-revert-an-svn-commit

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
svn merge -r COMMITTED:PREV .
```

or

```
svn merge -c -1708 path/to/file
```

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves  do `svn help merge`.  The `COMMITTED` and `PREV` targets are names that resolve to the previously committed revision, and the previous revision.  philreo also gave an example referencing the revision by number.

Comment: Ugh, **careful**, that does the *opposite* of what’s asked: it discards the changes to the file *locally* but keeps the commit upstream.