# Undo last svn commit?

Tags: svn

I accidentally added the wrong directory containing my files. Instead of adding a .cs file, I added the directory containing the .class file. How can I undo this action in svn ?

Comment: This is duplicate question for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527189/how-to-undo-a-commit-in-svn