# svn how to remove files which I forgot in svn

Tags: svn

Imagine I have the following repo history

1000 -- 1001 -- 1002

In revision number 1001 I added a few files in the subdirectories and commited it to 1002. But what actually I had to do was to remove all files from some of these subdirectories and then add new files and then commit it to revision number 1002.

As humans make mistake :) and so I was no exception. Now 1002 has all the new files and old files, and it will be very very hard if I have to remove files from 1002, as it will be a mix of all files. Is there a way I can easily do this in svn?

Thanks

Comment: You could always checkout revision 1000 and try again

Comment: You need to use "svn merge" option, check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527189/how-to-undo-a-commit-in-svn

Answer (score 1):

Start with a clean working directory and go back to the revision before adding the new files:

```
svn up -r 1001 .
```

Now, you can remove all files from the sub-directories. The files added in rev 1002 are not affected, because they do not exist in the revision of the working copy.

```
svn rm foo/* bar/*
```

Use `svn up` to update the working copy to the latest version. The files added in rev 1002 appear. Use `svn commit` to commit the files, that have been marked for removal previously:

```
svn up
svn commit
```