# Getting file to add that was previously on ignore-paths

Tags: git, svn

We have a large svn repository that locally we use git and git-svn to interact with.

Recently I created a repository but ignored a file starting with trunk. I fixed the ignore-paths so it ignores the directory trunk and not any file starting with trunk.

Now I get the git svn "was not found in commit" error since the commits git syncs with have the file but git is missing the original file commit.

Usually one would use git svn reset -rxxxx and git fetch -rxxxx but this is a two year old repository and I can not roll back to when the file was originally created.

How do I get git to pull the file down from svn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea 1:**

Create a svn working copy. Then:

```
svn rm <paths which you want un-ignore>
svn commit -m "ignore workaround"
svn merge -r COMMITTED:PREV .
svn commit -m "Reverting: ignore workaround"
```

Then just edit your `.git/config` to amend the `ignore-paths` and then `git svn rebase`.

**Idea 2:**

just copy all files manually into the git repo from svn repo, commit them and ditch the svn.

**Idea 3:**

Don't worry and reset the two year old git repo.

Comment: its a huge svn with 20-30 active developers so we aren't going with idea 2 and 3 :P

Comment: I think you got your SVN revision inverted. Shouldn't the merge be `svn merge -r PREV:COMMITTED .`?  My successful merge was done with `svn merge -r 32098:32097 .`

Comment: @big_gie Are you sure? This answer has the same as mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527189/how-to-undo-a-commit-in-svn

Comment: I could have screwed it up. The first time I did `svn merge -r 32097:32098 .` which failed, then did `svn merge -r 32098:32097 .` and it succeeded. So from what I understood it should be "MostRecentRevision:MostAncientRevision": you take the diff between the recent and the previous, then apply this diff to your work dir. This basically reverse the merge...

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to:

- Update to latest revision `git svn rebase`
- Copy the files manually (remove them from `.git/info/exclude` if any)
- Add them and commit using `git commit`
- Commit them using `git svn dcommit`

That should result in an error like:

> ERROR from SVN: RA layer file already exists: File X already exists W:
>   9166d48381296ed6038baf09425a6e6d84638c8c and refs/remotes/git-svn
>   differ, using rebase: :040000 000000
>   2ffb637dfc63727c4108c41c705a45e673e5dcbc
>   0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D      folder Current branch
>   master is up to date. ERROR: Not all changes have been committed into
>   SVN, however the committed ones (if any) seem to be successfully
>   integrated into the working tree. Please see the above messages for
>   details.

The `git commit` commit would exist, but the `git svn dcommit` would not in upstream `svn` repository (i.e. nothing will happen, fugazi, fairy dust, it doesn't exist).