# Can I delete a commit in Subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control, commit, cornerstone

Per accident I committed twice because I forgot to add two files. Can I remove a specific commit from the log?

[image: screenshot of log]

I want to delete commit № 4.

Comment: You may want to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566327/delete-all-traces-of-a-svn-commit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simple answer is "no", because Subversion doesn't know how to resolve the case when you add a commit, someone else updates their checkout, and then you remove the commit from history. There might or might not be a complex answer involving surgery on the Subversion storage.

Answer (score 5):

1. AFAICS, you have **not delete** r4, but **merge** with r5, yes?
2. In general, SVN commit history is immutable, as Sii said - and if you
   haven't rights delete/create repo - you can't do anything.

If you can delete current repo and create new with new history, you can try:

- `svnadmin dump` for getting human-readable (barely, I have to say)
  repository-dump, grok format and edit dump, delete repo, `svnadmin load`
  to recreate the repo
- another idea is (instead of editing dump) another
  SCM, which has a bridge to SVN (hg+MQ (histedit)+hg-git, f.e, will
  allow you to get repo and fold/delete changesets). For replacing
  old repository - see p.2 above

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it's just necessary to modify the commit comment associated with commit #4 to reflect the actual changes you made. You can do that with Subversion by modifying the SVN repository configuration. See the [Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#change-log-msg).

Answer (score -2):

Why?  Let Subversion keep the history - that's what it's for.  Check in early and often.  There's no need to erase commit #4.

Comment: Because I didn't add Site.cc and Site.hh (I forgot to do that), but the commit message says I did.

Comment: @WTP: The canonical solution is just committing a ninjafix and commenting it accordingly. If you want a "neat", one-commit-per-work-package history, Subversion (or Subversion alone) might not be the right tool for that.

Comment: If you did a clean check out of the project, would those two files appear?  If yes, then you did commit them.  Believe Subversion.

Comment: Well the proper solution in this particular case is to modify the commit message after it was committed.