# Is it impossible to cancel a bad commit with svn?

Tags: svn

Everybody hello !

I did a wrong commit just because it's easy to make a blunder with the shell.

I would like to cancel it and delete it so nobody will ever get my blunder on their local repository in the future like it is possible with Git.

Unfortunately, I don't find a way to do it.

I typed :

```
svn merge -r REVISION_WITH_THE_MISTAKE:PREVIOUS_REVISION .
```

but it just gets my repository back on the previous revision. The latest revision of the project still contains my mistake.

I did another commit to try to replace my previous bad commit but svn just creates another revision so it just keeps my mistake in the repository for good and I can't do anything.

Anybody has a solution ?

Thx!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all traces of a SVN commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566327/delete-all-traces-of-a-svn-commit)

Answer (score 0):

Revisions in Subversion are immutable. As a user, you cannot obliterate a revision using client tools. But you can roll back a revision. See

- [SVNBook | Undoing Changes](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo)
- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Roll back (Undo) revisions in the repository](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html)