# How to "undo" a commit in tortoise?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Say for example that I versions of some files needed only for my local dev machine, but I accidentally committed them. What is an easy way to revert all those files to a previous version and have that be the latest copy in svn?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747713/subversion-retract-accidental-checkin

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a [reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s04.html#svn-ch-4-sect-4.2).