# Deleting latest revision from svn

Tags: svn, git-svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subversion: Retract Accidental Checkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747713/subversion-retract-accidental-checkin)

Is there any way to delete the latest revision from SVN?

My latest SVNrevision has several files missing so I would like to switch to my previous revision and carry on from there. Is that possible? Any good suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you the server's administrator?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/747713/198011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot delete the revision, but you can "undo" it using reverse merge. Here's an example:

```
cd working/copy
svn merge -c -13 ^/repo/trunk
svn commit -m "Undoing change committed in r13."
```

See [Undoing Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

using svn revision history, revert the folder back to previous revision (required) and then commit the changes. This should take you to your required status of the code