# How to Undo Subversion commit

Tags: svn

I by mistake commit a file to one of the branch. I want to undo the commit, is it possible to do so. Please suggest me a solution.

--
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion: Retract Accidental Checkin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747713/subversion-retract-accidental-checkin)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`svn merge -c -REV`, where `REV` is the revision number of the commit you want to undo.

This should be performed on a clean local copy. The result will need to be checked in (of course, provided you're happy with it).

For a detailed explanation, see the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).

Comment: Isn't the correct line svn merge -c -Rev . ? Without the period, I get an error.