# Kinda <deleting> history in svn?

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subversion: Retract Accidental Checkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747713/subversion-retract-accidental-checkin)

In rev 10 I did something. It was bad. I regret it. I know you can't actually delete history from svn (that's the whole point, isn't it?) so I want rev 11 to be *exactly* like rev 9.

Comment: A duplicate of [Subversion: Retract Accidental Checkin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747713/subversion-retract-accidental-checkin), plus [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951742/how-to-undo-subversion-commit) also answers it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951742/how-to-undo-subversion-commit]. The other question is either irrelevant or wrongly answered (that is, to my understanding of course)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just revert it???

Right-click on the highest hierarchy you want to revert >> Revert or Revert to Revision

Comment: That's what I thought first (`revert` should revert it, right? wrong!) but as it turns out this should be done with `merge` as mentioned in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [Undoing Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.branchmerge.commonuses.html#svn.branchmerge.commonuses.undo) in the read-bin