# Remove a revision from SVN history

Tags: svn

I committed some sensitive data into the SVN by mistake. I don't want my collaborators to see these data. Can I revert the SVN to the previous state and remove the latest revision from SVN history (pretends that the latest commit were never made at all)?

Comment: @juergend, I do not think this is an exact duplicate: there may exist a different solution to this particular problem that does not involve revision removal.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot I diagree, the OP clearly asks to *remove the latest revision*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing a revision from SVN is rather problematic (see [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747713/subversion-retract-accidental-checkin) @juergend has provided). It has been done that way on purpose. One possible workaround that comes to mind: branch from the revision before your accidental commit and disallow access to the original branch.