# Removing SVN Revisions

Tags: svn

I know, that this topic is already well documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747713/subversion-retract-accidental-checkin). But I couldn't find the right answer.

Some years ago our boss said to a colleague, that he have to put *ALL* into the SVN. He did it several times and in sum round about **7.2 Gigs**. This is now completely outdated and it have to be removed from the SVN. Notice: **All the revisions are in a one SVN directory tree** and all documents in this directory tree should be deleted.

**I already know that a revision can't be removed, but 7.2Gigs are to much backupspace for an outdated business unit.**

```
root: svn://192.168.123.123/
delete: svn://192.168.123.123/OUTDATED_DIR_TREE 
hold: svn://192.168.123.123/java
hold: svn://192.168.123.123/cpp
```

Is it possible to export the java and cpp path into a new installation (with new revisions if needed) and **hold the comments and version tags**?

> svn, version 1.5.2 (r32768)
>   compiled Feb 25 2009, 16:12:21
>
> Copyright (C) 2000-2008 CollabNet.
>   Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
>   This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

Comment: What do you mean by ALL?

Comment: Fasten seatbelts! Images, Iso & doc files etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) should be what you need:

1. Export complete repo using svnadmin dump
2. Remove information from dump you do no longer need eg

   svndumpfilter --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs exclude OUTDATED_DIR_TREE < dumpfile > filtereddump
3. Recreate repo using svnadmin load

Of course all users have to freshly checkout the complete repository.

Comment: Okay! We would try it. Thanx a lot!

Comment: Thanx! that works fine for us. You mean  --drop-empty-revs instead of --dump-empty-revs. ;) I couldnt edit your answer.