# Netbeans : how to undo a commit in tortoise svn GUI

Tags: tortoisesvn, netbeans-7

I know this question has been asked many times, but I want to know how to it in netbeans.

I committed some changes, it was correct but I used the wrong account. Now, I need to undo the commit and recommit it using the correct account. How will I do this step by step in netbeans?

Here's the log of the wrong commit that I made. I want to be as sure as possible because this project is already running for several months already I dont want to ruin what my colleagues already made.

```
 Revision: 170 
 Author  : wrongAuthor 
 Date    : 08 27, 15 1:39:38 PM
 Migrated employee module to the new architecture. [for review]

 ==[IDE]== 08 27, 15 1:40:47 PM Committing... finished.
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to achieve this in Netbeans. Try solutions from:
possible duplicate of [Retract accidental checkin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747713/retract-accidental-checkin) via command line `svn` or TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Why must it be done in Netbeans? The method for undoing (as it were) a commit is [well-documented for the command-line client](http://stackoverflow.com/a/747758/1324345).

Comment: Even after the edit of your subject line, the answers/comments don't change.